# jquery on click not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi have tried to create a dropmenu to work on click so touch screens can use the menu.

```
$('a.dropsmall2').click(function() {
$(this).next('ul').slideToggle(500,'easeInOutQuad');
```

});

this part seems to function.

```
$('#dropmenu a').click(function() {
$(this).parents('ul').not('#dropmenu').hide('medium');
```

});

this part does work a bit but once you click it the menu opens and closes before it finally stays closed.

```
$('#dropmenu ul').mouseleave(function() {
$(this).slideToggle(500,'easeInOutQuad');
```

});
this part works but once the mouse leaves the menu is then able to be opened on hover rather then being clicked (not sure if its this part messing it up or the first part of the code.

jsfiddle ---> http://jsfiddle.net/e9e17adm/15

Comment: As @Vishnu Mentioned below, Include Jquery in your jsfiddle, else your example wont work.

Comment: `$(this).slideUp('500,easeInOutQuad');` is wrong, it should be: `$(this).slideUp(500, 'easeInOutQuad');` and the same for `slideDown()`, just check the DOC

Comment: done the above still not functioning. have the same problems

Comment: why mark down a question? its valid. trigger happy and waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS below, is your problem,

```
.dropmenu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease .1s;
    transition: height .3s ease .1s;
}
.dropmenu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You have already added ***:hover*** transition to your sub list. So, basically in the CSS you have mentioned that ***onhover*** of main ***LI*** the height of its submenu BI should increase to 27px.
It's just that initially in CSS the Submenu  is

```
display: "none";
```

So, you are not able to see the CSS transition which you see later on after click event.
Because, when you do an ***jquery onclick*** and do a **slideDown**
This also, attaches a

```
display: "block";
```

property in the inline style of the submenu ***UL*** element

And Hence, now you are able to see the transition effects of the CSS which you yourself have added above.

***UPDATE:***

Updated your fiddle to fix your issue. Let me know if that is what you wanted..

http://jsfiddle.net/e9e17adm/16/

Comment: ok thanks for adding more info, becoming clearer. is there a work around or must i remove the transition?

Comment: What is the exact functionality that you want ??

Comment: on click the menu opens, on mouseleave the menu closes, on click of a link the menu closes.

Comment: at present it opens but then can be hovered to open again. same for mouseleave. on click of a link the menu opens and closes a few times before it closes.

Comment: @alwayslearning:  onmouseleave of that particular Menu Element or the whole list element ?

Comment: @alwayslearning: Updated your fiddle to fix your issue. Let me know if that is what you wanted..
http://jsfiddle.net/e9e17adm/16/